How to save an enhanced image to a TIFF file
I have changed the brightness on an image, but I can't get the the changes to follow when writing to a TIFF file on disc. The stored file will look exactly as the original TIFF file.
This is my storage code:
    /**
 * saves an enhanced rendered image to a tiff file on disc.
 * @param inputname String
 * @param lr GridReaderLayer
 */
private void tiffSaver(String inputname,GridReaderLayer lr) {
    File file= new File(inputname);
    GridCoverage2DReader reader = lr.getReader();
    AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(file);
    try {
        Path fileToDeletePath = Paths.get(txtNewFilename.getText());
        File f = new File(txtNewFilename.getText());
        if (f.exists())
            Files.delete(fileToDeletePath);
        fileToDeletePath = Paths.get(filename);
        f = new File(filename);
        if (f.exists())
            Files.delete(fileToDeletePath);
        GridCoverage2D inCov = reader.read(null);
        ImageWorker iw = null;
        iw = new ImageWorker(inCov.getRenderedImage());
        final double[][] extrema = new double[2][];
        extrema[0] = iw.getMinimums();
        extrema[1] = iw.getMaximums();
        final int numBands = extrema[0].length;
        assert numBands == 1 : iw.getRenderedOperation();
        final int dataType = iw.getRenderedImage().getSampleModel().getDataType();
        double deltaR = extrema[1][0] - extrema[0][0];
        double minimumR = extrema[0][0];
        double maximumR = extrema[1][0];
        double deltaG = extrema[1][1] - extrema[0][1];
        double minimumG = extrema[0][1];
        double maximumG = extrema[1][1];
        double deltaB = extrema[1][2] - extrema[0][2];
        double minimumB = extrema[0][2];
        double maximumB = extrema[1][2];

        Process jiffle = (Process) Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl("ras", "Jiffle"));
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<>();
        inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SOURCE_NAME, new String[] { "src" });
        inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_COVERAGE, new GridCoverage2D[] { inCov });
        String scr = "deltaR = " + deltaR + "; ";
        scr = scr + "minimumR = " + minimumR + "; ";
        scr = scr + "maximumR = " + maximumR + "; ";
        scr = scr + "deltaG = " + deltaG + "; ";
        scr = scr + "minimumG = " + minimumG + "; ";
        scr = scr + "maximumG = " + maximumG + "; ";
        scr = scr + "deltaB = " + deltaB + "; ";
        scr = scr + "minimumB = " + minimumB + "; ";
        scr = scr + "maximumB = " + maximumB + "; ";
        scr = scr + "scaleR = (maximumR - minimumR)/deltaR; ";
        scr = scr + "offsetR = (minimumR - scaleR * maximumR); ";
        scr = scr + "scaleG = (maximumG - minimumG)/deltaG; ";
        scr = scr + "offsetG = (minimumG - scaleG * maximumG); ";
        scr = scr + "scaleB = (maximumB - minimumB)/deltaB; ";
        scr = scr + "offsetB = (minimumB - scaleB * maximumB); ";
        scr = scr + "dest[0] = scr[0] * scaleR + offsetR; ";
        scr = scr + "dest[1] = src[1] * scaleG + offsetG; ";
        scr = scr + "dest[2] = src[2] * scaleB + offsetB; ";
        inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SCRIPT, scr);
        Map<String, Object> output = ((org.geotools.process.Process) jiffle).execute(inputs, null);
        GridCoverage2D result = (GridCoverage2D) output.get(JiffleProcess.OUT_RESULT);
        final GeoTiffFormat format2 = new GeoTiffFormat();
        final GeoTiffWriteParams wp = new GeoTiffWriteParams();
        wp.setCompressionMode(GeoTiffWriteParams.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        wp.setCompressionType("LZW");
        final ParameterValueGroup params = format.getWriteParameters();
        params.parameter(AbstractGridFormat.GEOTOOLS_WRITE_PARAMS.getName().toString()).setValue(wp);
        GridCoverageWriter writer = null;
        if (result != null) {
            final File writeFile = new File(txtNewFilename.getText());
            writer = format2.getWriter(writeFile);
            writer.write(result, (GeneralParameterValue[]) params.values().toArray(new GeneralParameterValue[1]));
        }
        writer.dispose();

What am I missing?
